# Could not convert database value "1876-01-01 00:00:00-00:00:00" to Doctrine Type datetime

Tags: php, postgresql, datetime, doctrine-orm

Why doesn't Doctrine like old dates?

```
Exception was thrown : Could not convert database value "1876-01-01 00:00:00-00:00:00" to Doctrine Type datetime
```

And another:

```
Exception was thrown : Could not convert database value "0000-00-00 00:00:00-00:00:00" to Doctrine Type datetime
```

In my Entity I do override `datetime` and `datetimetz`

```
Type::overrideType('datetime', 'Doctrine\DBAL\Types\VarDateTimeType');
Type::overrideType('datetimetz', 'Doctrine\DBAL\Types\VarDateTimeType');
```

If I update the date to `1976-01-01 00:00:00-00:00:00` it works fine.

UPDATE:

So I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit, I also know that I have the 64 Bit time_t working from these tests:

> strtotime() produces different output on 32 and 64 bit systems running
>   PHP 5.3.3 (as mentioned previously).  This affects the "zero date"
>   ("0000-00-00 00:00:00") as well as dates outside the traditional 32
>   date range.

Tests:

```
strtotime("0000-00-00 00:00:00") returns FALSE on a 32 bit system.
strtotime("0000-00-00 00:00:00") returns -62169955200 on a 64 bit system.
```

When executing `echo strtotime("0000-00-00 00:00:00");` I get this:

```
php time_test.php -62169966000
```

so does Doctrine have the issue?

Comment: A 32-bit `time_t` value can only represent dates between the end of 1901 and the beginning of 2038.  To handle dates outside that range, you need a 64-bit `time_t`.  There are less than 25 years left until the 'end of the world' — when 32-bit `time_t` values based on the 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00 epoch run out.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is there somewhere I can set or tell Doctrine to use the 64 time_t?

Comment: Not knowing Doctrine at all, I'm not sure.  It would be a compile-time issue; you'd need a 64-bit build of PHP and Doctrine.  If you're on a 32-bit only system, you're probably stuck.  If you're on a 64-bit system (that is, the hardware is x86_64 or some other 64-bit chip), then you probably could rebuild all 64-bit and it might well work correctly.  However, it is not a trivial undertaking.  (For 'rebuild', you can read 'rebuild or download prebuilt' — you almost certainly need to have 64-bit software on a 64-bit system.)

Comment: I don't think these are postgresql timestamps. Certainly 0000-00-00 isn't a valid date.

Comment: @RichardHuxton no but I can default to a 0000-00-00 timestamp/datetime in Postgresql

Comment: Given your updated findings (and the platform information), it would appear, superficially, that Doctrine has issues that PHP does not. I'd be more inclined to trust this if you ran pure PHP (no Doctrine) and converted the time '1876-01-01 00:00:00'. I've just run a test on Mac OS X 10.7.5 with a 64-bit `time_t` and the `strptime()` function declines to recognize `1901-12-13 00:00:00` though it is OK with `1901-12-14 00:00:00` (somewhat to my surprise, I might add). More surprising: `strptime()` is happy to convert `9999-12-31 23:59:59` which also overflows 32-bits. The asymmetry is odd.

Comment: @Phil - no you can't have a PG timestamp default of 0000-00-00 - it's not a valid date.

Answer (score 2):

The epoch in PHP is either 1970 or 1901 depending on your system.

From the PHP manual:

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from
>   01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php